# How to hide Login when user is logged on in web2py?

Tags: web2py

I have a page with navigation like this

```
 <ul class="navigation">
<li><a class="home" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="about" href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a class="product" href="products.html">Products</a></li>
<li><a class="contact" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a class="bookings" href="bookings.html">Bookings</a></li>
<li><a class ="Login" href="user.html" id="Login">Login</a></li>
```

The Login system is made by default Auth. I am trying to hide the Login link if the user has logged on. I am not sure if this needs to be done in the client side or the server side and i cant find any help with this in the web2py book. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{if not auth.user:}}
<li><a class ="Login" href="user.html" id="Login">Login</a></li>
{{pass}}
```

The above will include the link conditionally, only when there is no logged in user. In the logged in case, you might also want to include a "Logout" link.